# Jenkins plugins to show what tabs a job is in?

Tags: plugins, jenkins, build, tabs, jobs

I've just taken over a new system with a lot of Jenkins tasks, some of which were added to multiple view tabs in error.

I can click on the tabs to see the jobs.  I'm looking for a plugin that will let me click on a job and display which view tabs the job is a member of.  I've searched; but can't find one and am wondering is someone knows if such a plugin exists.